# Prerequisites for learning general topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, book-recommendation

I want to learn general topology in order to apply it in electromagnetism.
I am an undergraduate student and I have a background in linear algebra (not at an advanced level), linear differential equations, multivariable calculus, and probability theory.
What are the prerequisites for learning general topology?

Also, every textbook that I find on general topology states that its level is for graduate studies.
So, do you have any textbooks that are for undergraduate-level topology?
Thank you.

Comment: There's Armstrong's "Basic Topology" which is the "Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics" series.  But I think the book is rather difficult for an undergraduate.  The hard part is not really the pre-requisite but the ability to read and write good clean proofs.  How are you at proofs?  If your proof skills need to be refined first, I suggest reading as elementary a book as you can find on "abstract algebra" because I think that's a subject that uses proofs but starts in a pretty basic way, basically square one.

Comment: You have to be comfortable with the use of set theory. Would be great (but not necessary) if you know some $\epsilon -\delta$ argument.

Comment: There is a free book "Topology Without Tears" http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~megereli/topbook.pdf  I would suggest reading Chapter 5 before Chapter 4.

Comment: @GregoryGrant i am pretty good at proofs.Although i will not be dealing with them at this level because all i want topology is for electromagnetism,which means i want to apply topology,so no mathematical proofs are required.I will surely check them out.I did proofs when studying the other subjects because i used those mathematics widely.But for this,i just want it for one subject,so no need to go THAT deep.To be more specific,i want to go as deep as learn linking numbers and the concept of helicity.Does your text include them(only linking numbers would be great)

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 does it have linking numbers?

Comment: @LandosAdam I've never actually encountered a user-perspective treatment of topology like we have for calculus, every book I know is proof based, basically for math majors.  I'm not sure such a treatment exists, but you could try to read Armstrong by just reading all the theorems and examples and skipping the proofs.  I'm sure you could get the basic idea of the subject that way.

Comment: @John from where can i study the things that you are proposing me to read?

Comment: @GregoryGrant ok i will download the book and check it out.I also checked out Baez's book on applied topology,and i think i might be following that one and returning back to your suggested book when i need somthing from the basics

Answer (score 2):

I think [Electromagnetic Theory and Computation: A Topological Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521801605) by Gross and Kotiuga might be just what you're looking for. However, it does assume that you know some general and algebraic topology to start with.

I would recommend that you read John Lee's [Topological Manifolds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1461427908) first. The text covers what you would expect in a typical topology book, but focusing primarily on manifolds, which are the physicist's preferred sort of spaces. However, it can be a bit difficult for beginners, since it assumes mathematical maturity, so you may want to keep a more elementary reference like [Munkres](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120320468) handy for when you get stuck.

Alternatively, you could read a more physicist-oriented introduction to topology like Nakahara's [Geometry, Topology, and Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750306068). I have not personally read it, but it seems like it should be accessible for you. There is also [Gauge Fields, Knots, and Gravity](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9810220340) by Baez and Munian, which is a very well-written book that provides good intuition, but is more of a survey than a textbook for learning the details.

Comment: Nakahara is a graduate's book,so it is difficult for me to read.Baez's book is good,so i will keep it beside me along Munkre's book and i will approach the subject the way that you suggested!Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are the rest of your suggested books on undergraduate level?

Comment: Lee's Topological Manifolds is also a graduate text, but it's probably the most appropriate for your goals in terms of its content. I think if you read it alongside Munkres (which is an undergrad text) it should be accessible.

Comment: ok,thanks a lot!

Comment: Erica Flapan's book [**When Topology Meets Chemistry: A Topological Look at Molecular Chirality**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0521664829) *might* be useful, perhaps as alternate reading for a gentler introduction to some of the topics.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is some set theory and you're good to go.

Read *Topology: A First Course by Munkres* first, this develops all the set theory that you need to know to tackle General Topology.

Do **not** read Introduction to Manifolds by Lee as a first book, read that as a second book or as a companion to Munkres, the reason I say this as that it would be really difficult as a first exposure, but as a second exposure to General Topology it will be a delight to read and supplement your knowledge.